# Azure stream analyics - Compiling query failed

Tags: azure, azure-stream-analytics

When I try to use the last function (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/mt421186.aspx). I get the following error:

> Compiling query failed.

```
SELECT
    deviceId
    ,System.TimeStamp as timestamp
    ,avg(events.externaltemp) as externaltemp
    ,LAST(System.Timestamp) OVER (PARTITION BY deviceId LIMIT DURATION(second, 1) when [externaltemp] is not null ) as Latest
INTO
    [powerBI]
FROM
    [EventHub] as events timestamp by [timestamp]

GROUP BY deviceId, TumblingWindow(second,1)
```

My last function looks very similar to the one in the msdn sample, so I'm not sure why there is a problem.

Comment: I've tried changing the is null for a less than statement, but that has no effect. I'm struggling to determine what is wrong with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using [externaltemp] in your query, but it is not included in group by. That is the reason. And "last" function does not allow aggregates inside it, so below wouldn't work as well

```
LAST(System.Timestamp) OVER (PARTITION BY deviceId LIMIT DURATION(second, 1) when avg([externaltemp]) is not null ) as Latest
```

It can be achieved by splitting the query into two steps, like this

```
with DeviceAggregates
as
(
SELECT
    System.TimeStamp as [Timestamp],
    deviceId,
    avg(events.externaltemp) as [externaltemp]
FROM
    [EventHub] as events timestamp by [timestamp]
GROUP BY 
    deviceId, 
    TumblingWindow(second,1)
),

DeviceAggregatesWithLast as
(
select 
    *,
    last([Timestamp]) over (partition by deviceId limit duration(second,1) when [externaltemp] is not null) [LastTimeThereWasANonNullTemperature] 
from 
    DeviceAggregates
)


select * 
INTO
    [powerBI]
from
    DeviceAggregatesWithLast
```